# Laravel syntax in HTML {{ }} vs <?= ?>

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following issue. I wrote the following code in my HTML source code.

```
      <form action = "/user/register" method = "post">
         <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?=csrf_token()?>">

         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td colspan = "2" align = "center">
                  <input type = "submit" value = "Register" />
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

      </form>
```

When I change the `<?=csrf_token()?>` to `{{csrf_token()}}`, I receive an error: `(TokenMismatchException)`.
Why? What is the difference between `<?=?>` and `{{}}` in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` escape string automatically by calling `htmlspecialchars` function and `<?= ?>` or `{!! !!}` don't escaping. You can read [**Displaying Data**](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data) documentation for blade templates. But `{{ csrf_token() }}` must be worked. Try using `{{ csrf_field() }}` to add input automatically:

```
<form action = "/user/register" method = "post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "name" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td colspan = "2" align = "center">
           <input type = "submit" value = "Register" />
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: I think the problem is/was that in the example I didn't use the blade template system.

Comment: You can simply add `.blade.php` instead of `.php` at the name of your file to use blade. @RuthBusari